# Installing pytest on Android

Tags: android

I have Android device and would like to install pytest on the device. However, I came across the challenge to obtain "easy_install". From my understanding, if we have easy_install, we could install pytest.

Another problem I have is using Terminal Emulator on Android. Some commands such as "whereis" is not recognized.

Can anyone advise me? 
JP

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Android, but it's a *nix at heart, right?  Try 'which' instead of 'whereis'.

Comment: Using the Terminal Emulator on a virtual device, both 'whereis' and 'which' give 'permission denied'. If you have a rooted device, it's possible the manufacturers removed those?  I have not tried python with android yet, so I have no answer for your first question.  I recommend paring this down to one question only though.

Comment: Using root, I tried whereis, which and even uname command. All they return is command not found.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
py.test --genscript=pytest
```

you can generate a standalone "pytest" script that might be able to just transfer to android and run.